# Abacus game/app, algorithm required

Tags: javascript, algorithm, phaser-framework

I am planning to develop an app/webpage containing a game based on Abacus calculator. After I complete it, I will give it to my kids Abacus training institute to help others.
Can anyone please guide me to some algorithm/workflow if available for abacus.
I have good knowledge of Javascript. I am planning to use Phaser.js for this.

Thanks

Comment: An algorithm to do *what*? As it stands, your question is unclear and very broad. Please [edit] your question to include more details of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could give more details about algorithm part. In my opinion you can use abacus for implementing basic mathematics, in algorithm part you can assign some cost to beads and operations. Then you can want user to minimize cost of the given mathematical operation.

Comment: That's the logic I am trying to implement.